# How to send a verification email and apply a cron job for every 2 hours until the user get verifed in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, node-cron

https://github.com/yashtiwari-kiwi/Library-Management-System/tree/task

please find the link of my repositery and help me with the question.

So i need to implement the cron job in emailVerify function in /src/controllers/user.controllers
Hence i need to send repeated email to client at 2 hour interval until the db verifiedEmail get true Please help me??

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to query your user database every 2 hours for a predefined property for example "isVerified" with one cron job. And then send an E-mail to all the users that are not verified.

Comment: Ok sure let me apply this and report back if its working or not 
BTW thanks for help.